# Simplify on provider side if possible

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.2

There is such item in QGIS layer render properties, how to use it? I have database in PostGIS. The problem is, that I have huge landcover polygon layer for which render is very slow. Would this help?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: In order to do *polygon* simplification, you need to identify left and right polygons to do the simplification the same way along shared borders.  This is not going to be efficient in a query, especially on a "huge landcover" layer. Instead, you want to pay that simplification cost once, then save it away as a scale-dependent layer.